# Using Leaflet and Leaflet.markerclusterer - how to loop all the markers?

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm trying to move away from Google Maps, as I'm fed up with how crappy slow they are now! I've decided to give Leaflet a go, and it seems like a good option. Below is my code:

```
initMap();

function initMap() {


    window.VARS.Map_Modal = L.map('google_map_modal_inner', {
                  center: [window.VARS.lat,window.VARS.lng],
                  zoom: 10,
                  maxZoom: 20,
                  zoomControl: false
                });

    new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'topright' }).addTo(window.VARS.Map_Modal);

    setTimeout(function() {

        window.VARS.Map_Modal.invalidateSize();// stop the grey tiles due to being a flex div

        L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox.streets',
            accessToken: 'xxx'
        }).addTo(window.VARS.Map_Modal);
    }, 500);

    getMarkers();


}

function getMarkers() {

    var extra_params = get_extra_params();
        extra_params["action"] = "load_results_cat";
        // other params pass in

    var the_url = '/cgi-bin/links/ajax.cgi';
    reqwest({
            url: the_url,
            type: 'json',
            method: 'post',
            data: extra_params,
            // timeout: 10000,
            error: function (err) {
                alert("ERROR");
             },
            success: function (data) {

                window.VARS.markers = []; // empty
                window.VARS.marker_vals = []; // empty

                window.VARS.markerCluster = L.markerClusterGroup();

                data.markers.forEach(function(item, i){

                        window.VARS.markerCluster.addLayer(
                                L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude])
                                .on("click", function(marker) {
                                    console.dir(marker);
                                })
                        );


                });

                window.VARS.Map_Modal.addLayer(window.VARS.markers);

            }
        });

}


function update_bottom_bar_visible() {


    var mapBounds = window.VARS.Map_Modal.getBounds();
    for (var i = window.VARS.markers.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {

        var m = window.VARS.markers[i];

        var shouldBeVisible = mapBounds.contains(m.getLatLng());

        if (shouldBeVisible) {
            console.log("This is visible");

        } else {
            console.log("This NOT visible");
        }

    }

}
```

This all works fine and the map shows ok. The problem I'm having is around this code:

```
    var shouldBeVisible = mapBounds.contains(m.getLatLng());

    if (shouldBeVisible) {
        console.log("This is visible");

    } else {
        console.log("This NOT visible");
    }
```

I can't get it to loop through the markers. What I need to do is go through all of the markers that are visible, and then show them in my bar below. I've taken out the guts of this script as its quite long - but this should hopefully be enough.

Here is a working example with the cluster tool, BUT it doesn't select the current markers in the viewport. This is the bit I need help with :)

https://jsfiddle.net/youradds/g7fd0k5z/1/

Please let me know if you need any more information

**UPDATE 2:** I managed to find some code from someone else, doing:

```
var i = 0;

window.VARS.markerCluster.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    var lat = layer.getLatLng().lat;
    var lng = layer.getLatLng().lng;
    console.dir("marker number("+i+"):"+lat+","+lng);
    //array.push({name:location,lat:lat,lng:lng});
    i++;
});
```

This DOES get the values of each layer, but it doesn't include the current markers inside the clusters. How do you extract that?

Comment: In the code you show, you never fill `markers` but try to loop on it. You fill `markerCluster` but add `markers` to the map.

Comment: @ghybs thanks for the reply. Maybe this is where my confusion is coming from. I'm adding them into `window.VARS.markerCluster` (as you have to, for the cluster stuff), but then how do I read them back on in the current viewport of the map?

Comment: I just pointed out inconsistencies in your code, which as is make it not functional at all. That may be just typos when copying your code to your question. But without clear code that shows your issue, it is difficult to help you. First debug the rest.

Comment: @ghybs thanks. Yeah the problem is I don't know how to loop over `window.VARS.markerCluster` and grab the markers out of it :/

Comment: @ghybs here is an example of adding the markers: https://jsfiddle.net/youradds/g7fd0k5z/1/ . I just need a way to select the markers that are in the current viewport (including the clusters). Will add this to the OP as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so I worked it out:

```
window.VARS.markerCluster.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    var lat = layer.getLatLng().lat;
    var lng = layer.getLatLng().lng;

    var shouldBeVisible = mapBounds.contains([lat,lng]);

    if (shouldBeVisible) {
        console.log("This is visible");
    } else {
        console.log("This NOT visible");

    }
});
```

Comment: If this works for you, please accept it, to help others who read the question in future.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica good point - I sometimes forget to come back and accept my own solutions , as it doesn't let you do it for a little bit :)

Comment: Two days, I believe. Thanks for accepting. And thanks for a helpful answer.